# Generating hirarchical structure out of a flat table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, kendo-treeview

**MAIN QUESTION:** What is the most efficient way to transform a flat table to a tree like hierarchical structure ?

**CONTEXT:**
Am a bit rusted and don't really know if this should be handled on SQL, PHP or even JavaScript (Kendo UI) side !

For a Kendo TreeView (HierachicalDataSource), i must export a json encoded tree structure from a table made from a single Select but with multiple JOINS to multiple tables... It generates a huge table of the following logical structure:

[image: Source Table]
My goal is to group by "date", "client", "employee" and to then list the "events". I need to get a structure like this one:

[image: Desired tree like structure from flat table]
I guess the best is a series of PHP loops ?... What could the code look like ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this PHP code:

```
$result = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    $date = $row['date'];
    $employee = $row['employee'];
    $client = $row['client'];
    $event = $row['event'];

    $result[$date][$client][$employee][] = $event;
}
```

I suppose you get `$data` through a simple query before this code.

Comment: I knew there was something simple like that ! Excuse me for having the wrong reflexes but i am from the C++ world so... If the want this to be key/value pairs like adding "text" before the "date" string and "child" before each nodes under "date" ?

Comment: First of all, I recommend you to read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do... Do you want to add a new level? Or a new child at the same level?

Comment: You gave me the perfect answer for my question... To finish the job on my side, i need to better understand the UI requirements and perhaps get back here with new refined question. Thanks !

Comment: New updated question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178114/making-a-json-tree-from-a-flat-php-sql-table